# CSS - float, fix and dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I'm not so versed in CSS and want to create a site with 3 columns where left and right side width are fixed while the center width is dynamic. Also the site should be at least compatible with IE (ver. 6 +), Firefox, Chrome and Safari. Any help?

My current code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#Content { width: 100%; height: 300px; }
div.left { float: left; width: 150px; }
div.middle { float: left; }
div.right { width: 150px; }
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="Content">
    <div class="left">Left</div>
    <div class="middle">Middle</div>
    <div class="right">Right</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Additional requirement: I want that the middle and right divs stay on the same line even when the browser size is so small.

EDIT:
I've found a site that has a similar structure:
http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm

However i want to have the left and right side fixed (150px). Can anyone help?

Comment: that is doable, show some of your code

Answer (score 0):

You have a fluid main holder, which then has 3 columns. What you then do is set the margin on the central element to the width of the columns on those sides. It's a pretty standard website model. [Here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/22257420/Dump/index.html)'s what dreamweaver automatically generates for me.

Comment: The example doesn't work on IE. When the browser size get's so small the floated elements go to the next line.

Comment: @Sys, What do you want it to do when the browser gets that small?

Comment: I added it above. Add. requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Will this do it?

```
<div style="position:absolute;margin-left:200px;margin-right:200px;">
    Awesome content
</div>
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div style="float:left;width:200px;height:100%;background-color:#FF0000;"></div>
    <div style="float:right;width:200px;height:100%;background-color:#FF0000;"></div>
</div>
```

Example on http://snuzzer.dk/pub/three_columns_fixed.html

Comment: Nope, sorry. See above new requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c2wVP/) example for you,

one thing you can do is to add an empty div after your floating elements and give it a `clear:both` style, to prevent the containing div from collapsing.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue with collapsing columns stems from the fact that you have not set fixed/minimum width for your container. Use min-width and max-width on your container to ensure that your website has a minimum width, which will force the browser to add horizontal scrollbars if it gets too small. You will need to set the min-width to at least the combined width of your two side columns to ensure that they do not collapse.

```
<style type="text/css">
#Content { min-width: 500px; max-width: 1000px; }
div.left { float: left; width: 150px; }
div.middle { float: left; }
div.right { float: right; width: 150px; }
</style>
```

If you are aiming for compatibility in IE 6 ( which seems almost pointless at this point, considering less than 2.5% of the people on the web still use IE6 - http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp ), use this technique: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/boxes/minwidth.html